# função imagecreatefrompng() não existe - erro undefined function

Tags: php, imagem, php-7

Estou tentando salvar uma imagem png, e quando rodo o script da erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng()
```

Mas pelo que vi, essa função é nativa do PHP:

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

Comment: Essa função faz parte da biblioteca GD, ela não deve estar instalada. Verifique seu php info.

Answer (score 2):

Com a ajuda do lazyFox e do bfavaretto encontrei o problema:

dei uma olhada no meu `info.php` que criei e coloquei na pasta raiz:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

E consultei pela biblioteca GD e realmente ela estava desabilitada.

O que fiz foi no Windows, no Linux adicionei abaixo:

---

#### NO WINDOWS

Entrei no meu `php.ini` e editei a linha contendo a extensão GD2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso reiniciar o servidor (Apache, NGinx, php -S)

---

#### LINUX

No Linux é só instalar a biblioteca com o gerenciador de dependências:

```
yum install php-gd # CentOS

apt-get install php7-gd # Ubuntu
```

Após isso reiniciar o serviço (Apache, NGinx, php -S)

---

Depois só para conferir, entrei novamente no info.php e realmente estava ativada e funcionou minha função:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: os que você colocou? só aquele comando já faz download da extensão e configura o php.ini do php no linux?

Comment: Sim, basta fazer restart ao serviço do apache.

Answer (score 1):

Essa função faz parte da biblioteca `php-gd`.
Precisas de a instalar na tua máquina para fazer uso da mesma.

```
yum install php-gd # CentOS

apt-get install php7-gd # Ubuntu
```

Comment: estou usando windows no momento, onde será que vejo isso?

Comment: Experimenta editar o ficheiro php.ini e procurar por algo como `;extension=php_gd2` se existir retira o `;` e reinicia o apache